# How to get the qtip style as shown on their homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

Just added [this plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) to my site. I want "qtips" exactly like the ones they have when you mouse over the big browser icons near the bottom.

I can't figure out what styles they're using for those. I've currently got this, but it doesn't come out the same:

```
$('a[title]').qtip({
    'position': {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center'
    },
    'style': {
        tip: true,
        classes: 'qtip-dark'
    }
});
```

Anyone know what they're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `qtip-tipsy` instead of `qtip-dark`.

```
$('a[title]').qtip({
    'position': {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center'
    },
    'style': {
        tip: true,
        classes: 'qtip-tipsy'
    }
});
```